# C++ const keyword in functions

Tags: c++, function, constants, function-qualifier

I understand when using it as follows:

```
int getX() const {...}
```

means that this function will not modify any of the variables used in its body. But what I didnt undertsnad is using const in 2 places, like the following:

```
const int* getX () const {...}
```

what's the use of putting the `const` keyword before the `int*`?

Comment: The last one simply means that the function returns a `const int*` as the result type. As would `int const*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first interpretation is wrong.

```
int getX() const { ... }
```

is a member function, and it cannot modify any data members or call any non-const for a given instance of the class that has that function.

```
const int* getX() const { ... }
```

returns a `const int*`, so it limits what you can assign to using it. It is a *non-const pointer to const int*, so you cannot modify the int it points to, but you can modify the pointer itself. For example:

```
const int* i = someInstange.getX(); // getX() returns const int*
i = someOtherFunction(); // another function returning const int*. OK to reassign i.
```

So `i` itself isn't `const`, but what it points to is:

```
(*i)++; // ERROR!
```

if you wanted to return a *const pointer to const int* you would need something like this:

```
const int * const getX() {}
```

The whole issue is further complicated because you can put the first `const` in different places without changing the meaning. For more information on that, look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-int-const).

Comment: so this just means that the return is const, and i must put it in a const variable?

Comment: That's right; you'd get an error if you'd try to assign the result to an `int*`.

Comment: @aizen92 It is a bit subtle. The pointer itself isn't const, so you can assign something else to it. What is const is what the pointer points to. I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @aizen92 I added more info to my answer, and a useful link.